# Making extruded polygons transparent

Tags: 3d-analyst, arcscene, extrude

Is there a way to make an extruded polygon transparent. I've tried going to the properties and changing the transparency but the polygon still looks like a solid block. I have an extruded polygon and a lot of point features I would like to see through the extruded polygon.